# Create temp table , insert into it and then select from it inside pgsql function

Tags: postgresql

Hi I want to Create temp table , insert into it and then select from it inside pgsql function.
can someone tell me how can I do that.

this is how I am trying but it is not working and saying incorrect syntax near select

```
    create or replace function myfunction()
  returns table ("id" int,"trans_doc_type" character varying
        )
as
$$
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "new_table_name"
   (
      "id" int,
      trans_doc_type VARCHAR(80)
   );   
    SELECT
        t.id ,
        t.trans_doc_type 
    INTO temp table "new_table_name"
    FROM
        "transaction" t;
    select * from "new_table_name";

$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Consider: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42924/postgresql-function-to-create-table

Comment: you can't do it directly in a function , you might want to make a procedure to do that or use dynamic sql inside function ( not recommended)

Comment: @eshirvana please add it as answer so I can mark it correct

Comment: Yes you can use a function to do this. See answer below.

Comment: Generally you do _not_ need a temporary table in cases like this. [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html)s would do the job in a much cleaner and more efficient manner.

Comment: ok thanks for information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `plpgsql` function:

```
create table transaction(id integer, trans_doc_type varchar);

insert into transaction values (1, 'test');
insert into transaction values (2, 'test2');

create or replace function myfunction()
  returns table ("id" int,"trans_doc_type" character varying
        )
as
$$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE new_table_name ON COMMIT drop AS
    SELECT
        t.id ,
        t.trans_doc_type
    FROM
        "transaction" t
    ;
   RETURN QUERY  select * from "new_table_name";


END;
$$
language plpgsql;

select * from myfunction();
 id | trans_doc_type 
----+----------------
  1 | test
  2 | test2
```

This can be shortened to:

```
create or replace function myfunction()
  returns table ("id" int,"trans_doc_type" character varying
        )
as
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT
        t.id ,
        t.trans_doc_type
    FROM
        "transaction" t
    ;
    
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: See shortened version added to answer.

Comment: thanks but my concern was using temp table and selecting from it which worked perfectly

Comment: I was aware of the other approach i,e shortned one

Comment: You don't even need PL/pgSQL here